# Failed to get response when sending xml data over SOAP

Tags: android, xml, soap

Am trying to send an xml over SOAP to get a particular response. Am trying to login using a default pin with me. Correct response will include a user id but am getting zeros.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    // Create the soap request object
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    // Set the property info for the to currency
    PropertyInfo value = new PropertyInfo();
    value.setName("xml");
    value.setValue(xml);
    value.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(value);


    // Create the envelop.Envelop will be used to send the request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);        
    envelope.dotNet = true;       

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);            
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

        result = response.getProperty(0).toString();           

        Log.i("RES", result);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        result = "EXCEP " + e.toString();
    }
```

my xml is

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<pinLogin xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <pin1>string</pin1>
  <pin2>string</pin2>
  <pin3>string</pin3>
  <pin4>string</pin4>
</pinLogin>
```

Am supposed to get a response like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <pinLoginResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <pinLoginResult>
    <username>string</username>
    <userID>guid</userID>
    <isBusinessUser>boolean</isBusinessUser>
    <functionOk>boolean</functionOk>
    <checkAmount>boolean</checkAmount>
    <refundRequested>boolean</refundRequested>
    <isPaid>boolean</isPaid>
    <duplicateUser>boolean</duplicateUser>
    <isvalid>boolean</isvalid>
    <funsdok>boolean</funsdok>
    <emailok>boolean</emailok>
    <recorddbadded>boolean</recorddbadded>
    <transisvalid>boolean</transisvalid>
    <user2isvalid>boolean</user2isvalid>
  </pinLoginResult>
 </pinLoginResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

But am getting something like this

```
anyType{userID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000;isBusinessUser=false; functionOk=false; checkAmount=false;refundRequested=false; ispaid=false; duplicateUser=false;
isValid=false; funsdok=false;emailok=false;recorddbadded=false;
transisvalid=false;user2isvalid=false;}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong...

Comment: Do you test your service in a browser ? test with some sample values.

Comment: yes i did test it. It does return a valid user id for a particular pin

Comment: result = response.getProperty(0).toString(); gives the above result right

Comment: yes it gives the result

Comment: i think there is some problem in the passing of value, please check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to crack it.

What worked for me was initially I was giving data in a complete string and added some data from edittext now I assigned the pin number to string and added those string to to Soap request via PropertyIndo also added xmlversiontag. I have added working code.

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "";
private final String URL = "";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "";
String _TAG = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";        
String pin1 = "a";
String pin2 = "b";
String pin3 = "8";
String pin4 = "d";
```

in my soapCall method

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo _pin1 = new PropertyInfo();
_pin1.setName("pin1");
_pin1.setValue(pin1);
_pin1.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo _pin2 = new PropertyInfo();
_pin2.setName("pin2");
_pin2.setValue(pin2);
_pin2.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo _pin3 = new PropertyInfo();
_pin3.setName("pin3");
_pin3.setValue(pin3);
_pin3.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo _pin4 = new PropertyInfo();
_pin4.setName("pin4");
_pin4.setValue(pin4);
_pin4.setType(String.class);


request.addProperty(_pin1);
request.addProperty(_pin2);
request.addProperty(_pin3);
request.addProperty(_pin4);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);        
envelope.dotNet = true;

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
       androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag(_TAG);
       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
       result = response.getProperty(0).toString();
       Log.i("RES", result);
    }
catch(Exception e){
       Log.i("ERR" , e.toString());
}
```

Also do add permission for Internet in your manifest file. I hope this may come useful for someone.